# Quelle est la difference entre « avoir la gueule de bois » et « avoir mal aux cheveux » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Qu'est-ce que la différence entre « *avoir la gueule de bois* » et « *avoir mal aux cheveux* » ? J'ai entendu les deux, mais je ne sais pas quelle est la différence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« **Mal aux cheveux** » est utilisé par métonymie pour désigner les maux de têtes qui suivent un abus d'alcool.

« **Avoir la gueule de bois** » s'emploie dans les mêmes circonstances mais avec une petite nuance puisqu'à l'origine, l'expression décrivait les sensations de la bouche qui suivent l’absorption d'une grande quantité d'alcool (cf. tlfi: « *Avoir la bouche rêche et empâtée, après un excès de boisson.* » ). Aujourd'hui la référence à la bouche s'est perdue et gueule de bois désigne l'état général qui suit un abus d'alcool.

« **Avoir la gueule de bois** » et encore plus « **se réveiller avec la gueule de bois** » se rencontre aussi très souvent au sens figuré pour désigner l'état d'un personne qui déchante, prends pleinement conscience des conséquences d'un événement malheureux survenu la veille, par exemple une défaite électorale, sportive, une faillite, etc.

Comment: Merci.  Ça a du sense :).

Answer (score 0):

Je dirai que c'est plus ou moins la même chose, ces expressions sont utilisées pour qualifier un état après un lendemain de fête (cuite).

Mal de crâne, fatigue, desydratation

Answer (score 0):

Gueule de bois: hangover. It’s the main way to say it. 
Mal aux cheveux means hangover too, but is less used. 
I think Capitaine Haddock uses that expression after the Yeti steals his whisky in Tintin in Tibet...

Comment: Please have a look to https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30/1109

Comment: Toutes mes excuses. Je suis nouvelle sur le site. Je ne savais pas qu’il était prérérable d’expliquer en Français, et non an Anglais.

Comment: Pour être plus clair, il est plus logique de répondre en français à une question exprimée dans cette langue car il n'est pas certain que la personne l'ayant posée comprenne (mieux) l'anglais, même si c'est souvent le cas.